# How to call specific category from array

Tags: php, arrays

1. Question:

I want to call a specific category to show up in pages related to it.

For example this code `<?php foreach ($categories as $name => $value) { echo $categ[$name]; }  ?>` is calling all categories out, I just want to call for example title_1 or title_2 or title_3...  show up on a specific page.

1. Question:

How can I include an img to specific category (example `'title_1' => "<img src='' />Splošno",`

Here is array:

```
$categories= array(

'title_1' => "Splošno", 
"merch1" => array( "Aparati", "set7", "type"), 
"merch12" => array( "Cd,dvd", "set7", "type"), 
"merch9" => array( "Darila", "set7", "type"), 
"merch3" => array( "Dodatna Oprema", "set7", "type"), 
"merch6" => array( "Elektronika", "set7", "type"), 
"merch17" => array( "Fotografija in Optika", "set7", "type"), 
"merch27" => array( "Gradnja", "set7", "type"), 
"merch4" => array( "Hobi,Zbirateljstvo", "set7", "type"), 
"merch25" => array( "Igrače,otroška oprema", "set7", "type"), 
"merch2" => array( "Knjige,revije,stripi", "set7", "type"), 
"merch13" => array( "Kmetijstvo,gozdarstvo", "set7", "type"), 
"merch15" => array( "Kolesa", "set7", "type"), 
'newcol_1' => "", 
"merch18" => array( "Lepota in zdravje", "set7", "type"), 
"merch16" => array( "Navtika", "set7", "type"), 
"merch10" => array( "Nakit", "set7", "type"), 
"merhc29" => array( "Oblačila,obutev...", "set7", "type"), 
"merch22" => array( "Prehrana", "set7", "type"), 
"merch7" => array( "Pohištvo", "set7", "type"), 
"merch20" => array( "Poslovna oprema", "set7", "type"), 
"merch32" => array( "Programska oprema", "set7", "type"), 
"merch34" => array( "Peči in kamini", "set7", "type"), 
"merch26" => array( "Rekreacija,šport", "set7", "type"), 
"merch21" => array( "Rastline", "set7", "type"), 
"merch5" => array( "Računalniki", "set7", "type"), 
"merch30" => array( "Ribolov", "set7", "type"), 
"merch8" => array( "Šport", "set7", "type"), 
"merch33" => array( "Športna oprema", "set7", "type"), 
'newcol_2' => "", 
"merch14" => array( "Telefoni", "set7", "type"), 
"merch23" => array( "Turizem", "set7", "type"), 
"merch31" => array( "Televizorji", "set7", "type"), 
"merch24" => array( "Umetnine,starine", "set7", "type"), 
"merch11" => array( "Vstopnice", "set7", "type"), 
"merch19" => array( "Drugo", "set7", "type"), 
'title_2' => "Osebni Stiki", 
"manw" => array( "Moški išče Žensko", "set1", "age,goal"), 
"manm" => array( "Moški išče Moškega", "set1", "age,goal"), 
"manw_repl" => array( "Moški išče Žensko (komentarji)", "set4", "h"), 
"womenm" => array( "Ženska išče Moškega", "set1", "age,goal"), 
"womenw" => array( "Ženska išče Žensko", "set1", "age,goal"), 
"wlkm_repl" => array( "Ženska išče Moškega (komentarji)", "set4", "h"), 
'title_3' => "Nepremičnine", 
"rlest7" => array( "Apartmaji", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest3" => array( "Garaže,Skladišča", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest9" => array( "Hiše", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest2" => array( "Kmetije in Zemlja", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest5" => array( "Nepremičnine za Najem", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest6" => array( "Počitniški Najemi", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest1" => array( "Poslovni Prostori,Pisarne", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest4" => array( "Stanovanja", "set7", "type"), 
"rlest8" => array( "Drugi Oglasi", "set7", "type"), 
'title_4' => "Zaposlitev", 
"job6" => array( "Avtomobilizem", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job7" => array( "Bančništvo,Finance", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job17" => array( "Delo Od Doma", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job8" => array( "Farmacija", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job16" => array( "Fitnes,Šport", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job14" => array( "Izobraževanje", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job15" => array( "Inžinerska Dela", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job4" => array( "Kmetijstvo", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job20" => array( "Management", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job23" => array( "Marketing", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job25" => array( "Neprofitna Dela", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job2" => array( "Oglaševanje", "set2", "jobtype"), 
'newcol_3' => "", 
"job30" => array( "Prevozi", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job21" => array( "Pravo", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job22" => array( "Proizvodnja", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job1" => array( "Računovodstvo", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job9" => array( "Računalniški Inženiring", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job11" => array( "Projektna podpora", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job24" => array( "Splošno Upravljanje", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job29" => array( "Trgovska stroka", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job32" => array( "Turizem in Gostinstvo", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job3" => array( "Uprava,Pisarna", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job5" => array( "Umetnost,Medija", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job31" => array( "Veterinarske storitve", "set2", "jobtype"), 
'newcol_4' => "", 
"job27" => array( "Začasna Dela", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job28" => array( "Založništvo", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job18" => array( "Zdravstvena Dela", "set2", "jobtype"), 
"job33" => array( "Zaposlitve-Drugo", "set2", "jobtype"), 
'newcolumn_1' => "", 
'title_5' => "Motorna vozila", 
"veh5" => array( "Avto Deli", "set7", "type"), 
"veh6" => array( "Avtobusi", "set7", "type"), 
"veh9" => array( "Čolni", "set7", "type"), 
"veh8" => array( "Gradbena Mehanizacija", "set7", "type"), 
"veh2" => array( "Kombi,Minikombi", "set7", "type"), 
"veh3" => array( "Motorna Kolesa", "set7", "type"), 
"veh1" => array( "Osebna Vozila", "set7", "type"), 
"veh4" => array( "Prikolice,Drugo", "set7", "type"), 
"veh7" => array( "Tovornjaki", "set7", "type"), 
"veh11" => array( "Viličarji", "set7", "type"), 
"veh10" => array( "Druga Vozila", "set7", "type"), 
'title_6' => "Podarim", 
"pod1" => array( "Avtomobili", "set6", ""), 
"pod2" => array( "Akustika,video,foto", "set6", ""), 
"pod5" => array( "Gospodinjski aparati", "set6", ""), 
"pod3" => array( "Otroška oprema in igrače", "set6", ""), 
"pod4" => array( "Oblačila in obutev", "set6", ""), 
"pod7" => array( "Računalništvo", "set6", ""), 
"pod6" => array( "Stanovanjska oprema", "set6", ""), 
'newcol_5' => "", 
"pod8" => array( "Stroji,orodja,material", "set6", ""), 
"pod10" => array( "Športna oprema", "set6", ""), 
"pod9" => array( "Umetnine,starine", "set6", ""), 
"pod12" => array( "Ostalo", "set6", ""), 
'title_7' => "Gostinska oprema", 
"bar1" => array( "Aparati za pripravo jedi", "set7", "type"), 
"bar2" => array( "Aparati za pripravo pijač", "set7", "type"), 
"bar3" => array( "Drobni inventar", "set7", "type"), 
"bar4" => array( "Grelni elementi", "set7", "type"), 
"bar5" => array( "Hladilni elementi", "set7", "type"), 
"bar6" => array( "Ledomati", "set7", "type"), 
'newcol_6' => "", 
"bar7" => array( "Pohištvo", "set7", "type"), 
"bar8" => array( "Pomivalni stroji,korita", "set7", "type"), 
"bar9" => array( "Samopostrežne linije", "set7", "type"), 
"bar10" => array( "Točilni pulti", "set7", "type"), 
"bar11" => array( "Ostala oprema", "set7", "type"), 
'title_8' => "Živali", 
"pet8" => array( "Akvaristika", "set5", "type"), 
"pet14" => array( "Drobnica", "set5", "type"), 
"pet4" => array( "Eksotične Ptice", "set5", "type"), 
"pet9" => array( "Glodalci", "set5", "type"), 
"pet15" => array( "Goveda", "set5", "type"), 
"pet11" => array( "Hrana za živali", "set5", "type"), 
"pet17" => array( "Kunci", "set5", "type"), 
"pet6" => array( "Konji", "set5", "type"), 
"pet2" => array( "Mačke", "set5", "type"), 
"pet12" => array( "Nega malih živali", "set5", "type"), 
"pet18" => array( "Osli", "set5", "type"), 
"pet21" => array( "Oprema za akvaristiko", "set5", "type"), 
'newcol_7' => "", 
"pet22" => array( "Oprema za glodalce", "set5", "type"), 
"pet23" => array( "Oprema za mačke", "set5", "type"), 
"pet24" => array( "Oprema za pse", "set5", "type"), 
"pet25" => array( "Oprema za ptice", "set5", "type"), 
"pet26" => array( "Oprema za teraristiko", "set5", "type"), 
"pet27" => array( "Oprema za ostale živali", "set5", "type"), 
"pet3" => array( "Psi", "set5", "type"), 
"pet1" => array( "Ptice", "set5", "type"), 
"pet7" => array( "Plazilci", "set5", "type"), 
"pet19" => array( "Perutnina", "set5", "type"), 
"pet20" => array( "Prašiči", "set5", "type"), 
"pet5" => array( "Ribe", "set5", "type"), 
'newcol_8' => "", 
"pet10" => array( "Teraristika", "set5", "type"), 
"pet13" => array( "Varstvo Živali", "set5", "type"), 
"pet28" => array( "Živali iz zavetišč", "set5", "type"), 
"pet29" => array( "Drugo", "set5", "type"), 
'title_9' => "Skupnosti", 
"commun3" => array( "Dogodki,Zabave", "set6", ""), 
"commun5" => array( "Izgubljeni,Najdeni Predmeti", "set6", ""), 
"commun2" => array( "Obvestila", "set6", ""), 
"commun1" => array( "Partnerji", "set6", ""), 
"commun4" => array( "Prijatelji", "set6", ""), 
"commun7" => array( "Poroke", "set6", ""), 
"commun8" => array( "Prostovoljci", "set6", ""), 
"commun6" => array( "Rojstni Dnevi", "set6", ""), 
'newcolumn_2' => "", 
'title_10' => "Programiranje", 
"soft3" => array( "ASP Programiranje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft11" => array( "Baze Podatkov", "set3", "type"), 
"soft7" => array( "C++ Razvoj", "set3", "type"), 
"soft8" => array( "Delphi Programiranje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft5" => array( "E-Commerce", "set3", "type"), 
"soft6" => array( "Java, JavaScript", "set3", "type"), 
"soft12" => array( "Mrežno Povezovanje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft1" => array( "Perl Programiranje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft2" => array( "PHP Programiranje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft4" => array( "Spletno Oblikovanje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft10" => array( "UNIX Programiranje", "set3", "type"), 
"soft9" => array( "Visual Basic", "set3", "type"), 
'title_11' => "Storitve", 
"servs20" => array( "Avto električar", "set3", ""), 
"servs16" => array( "Avtovleka", "set3", ""), 
"servs15" => array( "Avtoprevozništvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs17" => array( "Banka", "set3", ""), 
"servs18" => array( "Catering", "set3", ""), 
"servs19" => array( "Čiščenje objektov", "set3", ""), 
"servs4" => array( "Domača Opravila", "set3", ""), 
"servs49" => array( "Denarna posojila", "set3", ""), 
"servs21" => array( "Elektro servis", "set3", ""), 
"servs38" => array( "Fasaderstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs24" => array( "Graverstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs23" => array( "Grafično oblikovanje", "set3", ""), 
"servs3" => array( "Gradbene storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs5" => array( "Kozmetične storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs10" => array( "Kovinarstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs25" => array( "Keramičarstvo", "set3", ""), 
'newcol_9' => "", 
"servs26" => array( "Klima servis", "set3", ""), 
"servs28" => array( "Krovstvo,kleparstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs48" => array( "Kamnoseštvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs29" => array( "Lektoriranje", "set3", ""), 
"servs30" => array( "Manikura", "set3", ""), 
"servs50" => array( "Masaža", "set3", ""), 
"servs31" => array( "Mizarstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs32" => array( "Prevajanje", "set3", ""), 
"servs33" => array( "Plesna šola", "set3", ""), 
"servs34" => array( "Pogrebne storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs14" => array( "Prevozi", "set3", ""), 
"servs8" => array( "Računovodske storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs11" => array( "Rent a car,avtodom", "set3", ""), 
"servs12" => array( "Računalniške storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs9" => array( "Strojne inštalacije", "set3", ""), 
"servs13" => array( "Svetovanje", "set3", ""), 
'newcol_10' => "", 
"servs35" => array( "Selitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs36" => array( "Slikopleskarstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs37" => array( "Steklarstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs46" => array( "Športna vadba,tečaji", "set3", ""), 
"servs44" => array( "Turistična kmetija", "set3", ""), 
"servs45" => array( "Tiskarstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs1" => array( "Varstvo Otrok", "set3", ""), 
"servs2" => array( "Varstvo Nepokretnih", "set3", ""), 
"servs6" => array( "Vrtna Opravila", "set3", ""), 
"servs43" => array( "Vedeževanje", "set3", ""), 
"servs39" => array( "Zlatarstvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs40" => array( "Zdravsteve storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs41" => array( "Zavarovalništvo", "set3", ""), 
"servs42" => array( "Wellness storitve", "set3", ""), 
"servs7" => array( "Druge Storitve", "set3", ""), 
'title_12' => "Glasba", 
"mus2" => array( "Glasbeniki", "set8", ""), 
"mus4" => array( "Glasbeni Inštrumenti", "set8", ""), 
"mus1" => array( "Obvestila", "set8", ""), 
"mus3" => array( "Skupine", "set8", ""), 
"mus5" => array( "Glasbene Storitve", "set8", ""), 
"mus6" => array( "Zbirateljstvo", "set8", ""), 
"mus7" => array( "Drugi Glasbeni Oglasi", "set8", ""), 
"evntcl" => array( "Koledar Dogodkov", "set6", ""), 
"evcl_rpl" => array( "Koledar Dogodkov (komentarji)", "set4", "h")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
echo $categories['title_1'][0] // this will display the first element of the 'title_1' element
```

I don't understand what you mean with question #2.

ps: pozdrav v Slovenijo :)

Comment: Example, 'title_1' => "<img src='' />Splošno",

Answer (score 0):

like

```
print_r($categ['job21']);
```

and

```
echo $categ['job21'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have simple two dimensional array .. just use array key to print particular array like

```
foreach($categories['merch1'] as $val )
{
    echo $val. "<br>";
}
```

Now its dependupon you how you are utilizing this..
hope you understand.